# Generate random time within range and is odd

Tags: excel, xlsx

I need to generate a random time between a range of 6AM and 6PM that only contains an odd numbered hour (ex. I could only have hours of 7, 9, 11, ect.), the minutes to not matter they can be even.

Comment: `=TIME(RANDBETWEEN(3,8)*2+1,RANDBETWEEN(0,59),RANDBETWEEN(0,59))`

Comment: Would something like: =TIME(ODD(RANDBETWEEN(6, 18)),RANDBETWEEN(0,59),0) work if i wanted no seconds as well?

Comment: Yeah, that would work.

Comment: Then say in a separate column I'd want to add a random amount of time between 35 min to 1 hr and 45 min to the value in the previous column how would I got about that? I've tried =RANDBETWEEN(TIME(0, 35, 0), TIME(1, 45, 0)) then adding that to the value of the previous column, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=TIME(CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,6),7,9,11,13,15,17),0,0)
```

[image]